Altium Tracks Automatically Roll Back During Interactive Routing - Why?
I'm trying to increase the copper area across the through-hole pad in Altium Designer to prevent damage during soldering and desoldering. However, when I'm close to completing the track, it automatically rolls back. I've ensured that the 'Automatically Remove Loops' option is deselected, but the issue persists. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how to resolve it?
I know this can be achieved using polygons, but that is more time-consuming compared to using tracks for each pad.

Actually, I want to achieve this type of tracing, which helps to thicken the track and prevent damage while desoldering and soldering components, mainly for through-hole components in power supplies and DC-DC converters.


I can't see what you're doing in the animation, but the proper way to increase the amount of copper around a pad is to increase the pad size.

Is there a particular reason you want to do it this way rather than just editing the pad?

Actually, increasing the pad size to be larger for smaller through-hole components will make the layout look less professional.

Because you're touching the trace destination.  It is, I believe, completing the route from the point it was started, to the destination object. Your big loop doesn't mean anything to the tool, and it takes the direct path.
To increase pad area, edit the pad manually, or place a Region.  This can be done without increasing soldermask opening by using a Region, or setting a negative soldermask expansion value.  Traces are a particularly brittle choice for this kind of augmentation, as they won't be dragged with the Component, they tend to disappear on reroute (see PCB Preferences; Interactive Routing, Automatically Remove Loops/Net Antennas), and they aren't controlled centrally (e.g. you can simply query all pads of a given shape and resize them all at once).
FWIW, I prefer 65 x 75 mil pads with 40 mil holes for 0.025" square pin x 0.1" pitch header stock. Easy to route between, easy to solder, loose fit (but not grossly so) even on cheap (poorly aligned?) headers.

I have updated the question in more detail. Actually, increasing the pad size to be larger for smaller through-hole components will make the layout look less professional.

Moreover, is there any way in Altium to implement such types of track loops, or can we only do it using polygons and regions?

Those Japanese style layouts may be facilitated with specific tools, I don't know what they use; but I've used Polygons to do that in Altium. And yes, it's very tedious. You can place Trace objects (P, L) arbitrarily, but they become regular routed traces when the net is assigned, and are just as liable to pop out of existence via Auto Remove Loops.

You are creating a loop with the track that is way tracks Automatically Roll Back During Interactive Routing
